# Stylus concatenate variable and string

Tags: stylus

Following code

```
for $i in (1..81)
   .block:nth-child({$i})
      transition transform 500ms ease $i\s
```

will be compiled to

```
.block:nth-child(1) {
    transition: transform 500ms ease 1 s;
}

......
```

But that space between number and seconds is redundant!

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
for $i in (1..81)
   .block:nth-child({$i})
     transition transform 500ms ease 1s * $i
```

That's actually quite similar to the example given in [**Selector Interpolation**](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/interpolation.html#selector-interpolation) section of Stylus documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unit()` function:

```
for $i in (1..81)
  .block:nth-child({$i})
    transition transform 500ms ease unit($i, 's')
```